# Delphi: ListView (vsReport) single column header caption with custom font color?

Tags: windows, delphi, listview, delphi-xe2, columnheader

In a ListView with vsReport ViewStyle, how can I customize the font color of just any single column header caption? For example (the second column header caption has a red font color):
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would handle the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) header notification code and respond to this notification message with the `CDRF_NEWFONT` return code at the `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` rendering stage. The following code shows how to extend list view controls to have the event for specifying header item font color:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, CommCtrl, StdCtrls;

type
  TGetHeaderItemFontColorEvent = procedure(Sender: TCustomListView;
    ItemIndex: Integer; var FontColor: TColor) of object;
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  private
    FHeaderHandle: HWND;
    FOnGetHeaderItemFontColor: TGetHeaderItemFontColorEvent;
    procedure WMNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotify); message WM_NOTIFY;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  published
    property OnGetHeaderItemFontColor: TGetHeaderItemFontColorEvent read
      FOnGetHeaderItemFontColor write FOnGetHeaderItemFontColor;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure GetHeaderItemFontColor(Sender: TCustomListView;
      ItemIndex: Integer; var FontColor: TColor);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TListView }

procedure TListView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  FHeaderHandle := ListView_GetHeader(Handle);
end;

procedure TListView.WMNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotify);
var
  FontColor: TColor;
  NMCustomDraw: TNMCustomDraw;
begin
  if (AMessage.NMHdr.hwndFrom = FHeaderHandle) and
    (AMessage.NMHdr.code = NM_CUSTOMDRAW) then
  begin
    NMCustomDraw := PNMCustomDraw(TMessage(AMessage).LParam)^;
    case NMCustomDraw.dwDrawStage of
      CDDS_PREPAINT:
        AMessage.Result := CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
      CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
      begin
        FontColor := Font.Color;
        if Assigned(FOnGetHeaderItemFontColor) then
          FOnGetHeaderItemFontColor(Self, NMCustomDraw.dwItemSpec, FontColor);
        SetTextColor(NMCustomDraw.hdc, ColorToRGB(FontColor));
        AMessage.Result := CDRF_NEWFONT;
      end;
    else
      AMessage.Result := CDRF_DODEFAULT;
    end;
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.OnGetHeaderItemFontColor := GetHeaderItemFontColor;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetHeaderItemFontColor(Sender: TCustomListView;
  ItemIndex: Integer; var FontColor: TColor);
begin
  case ItemIndex of
    0: FontColor := clRed;
    1: FontColor := clGreen;
    2: FontColor := clBlue;
  end;
end;

end.
```

The whole project you can [**download from here**](https://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/downloads/detail?name=15054423.ZIP). Here's the result of the above example:

[image]

Comment: +1, There is a small painting problem (with Subitems 1/2) if you select `Item 1` and then resize `Column 1` (Subitems are smeared).

Comment: @kobik, that's not related to this code. I can reproduce what you've described (Windows 7) just with this list view in a plain new project. So it's just another non-virtual mode list view bug.

Comment: @TLama, might be. I just executed your EXE and reported what I see :)

Comment: @kobik, the same you will see also if you just cut & paste that list view to a different project ;-) This you can workaround by disliked `DoubleBuffered` property or resolve by using virtual mode. I bet there's a bunch of reports about it in QC.

Comment: @TLama, When I compile your code works fine with D7 (with or without XP manifest). However Themes are not applied to the ListView items (D7 issue). I think you are quit right that this has to do with Delphi implementation of `TListView`.

Comment: Sorry, test your Project1.exe file from the .zip . No colored Column Header. Compiled it with Delphi 2010 the same. Windows XP .

Comment: @moskito-x: It's a bit unclear what you observe. I'm quite sure TLama's code works, though. It might happen, however, that Windows XP doesn't support this. After all, we are working with a native OS control, not a control written in Delphi... But I think it works on XP.

Comment: @moskito-x, I don't have Windows XP, so I can't verify, but this should work since Windows 2k till now (there's even no mention about higher version of Comctl32.dll e.g.).

Comment: I'll try this at work tomorrow (got a XP system there). I think it will work just fine there.

Comment: Tested: worked on Windows 2000 and Vista but not in Windows XP. Even if a switch to Xp Standard Theme.

Comment: TLama, @moskito-x: I can confirm that this does NOT work on Windows XP with visual themes (Luna) on. However, it does work in the Windows classic theme. I don't know why, but my guess is that Microsoft simply didn't implement custom draw completely for themed controls in XP, the first version of Windows to use themes. This should be documented at MSDN, however. Is it? [It's also possible that there is some subtle bug in TLama's code, but I doubt that.]

Comment: (cont.) So maybe there was indeed some truth in my initial (now deleted) comment to the Q: "it is awkward to make this work on every version of Windows, and with/without visual themes".

Comment: @Andreas, moskito-x, thanks for the testing! Unfortunately, I couldn't find any mention about some issue related to the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` header notification on Windows XP. Does my event ever fire on Windows XP ? I mean, is the list view notified by the `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` notification of its header there ? If so, then must be something wrong with the passed canvas handle or the returned `CDRF_NEWFONT` result is ignored somehow.

Comment: @TLama Many thanks, you're a genius! However, when I change a particular header caption font-color dynamically at run-time, I need to hover the mouse pointer over the particular column header to have it redrawn in the desired color:
    `case ItemIndex of
      0:
        begin
          if Condition1 then
            FontColor := clRed
          else if Condition2 then
            FontColor := clBlue;
        end;
      1: ...
      2: ...
    end;`
So how can I have the column header caption redrawn programmatically?

Comment: Found the solution: `Condition1 := True; InvalidateRect(ListView1.FHeaderHandle, nil, True);`

Comment: You're welcome! And yes, the `InvalidateRect` for the header control as you've shown is the best way to go to force the header to invalidate.

Comment: Is it also possible to draw the header background in a custom color? If yes, how?

Answer (score 6):

You can get the native header control from the listview and then mark the specific item of your column as owner drawn. You only need to change the text color (if you don't remove the *string* flag) when the header item requests to be drawn. The drawing message will be sent to the header's parent - the listview, hence you need to handle the message there. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775238.aspx#_win32_header_owner_draw) for owner drawn header controls.

Example code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
     ...
  private
    FLVHeader: HWND;
    FSaveLVWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure LVWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
    procedure SetHeaderItemStyle(Index: Integer);
  end;

..
uses commctrl;
..

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FLVHeader := ListView_GetHeader(ListView1.Handle);
  SetHeaderItemStyle(1);

  FSaveLVWndProc := ListView1.WindowProc;
  ListView1.WindowProc := LVWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetHeaderItemStyle(Index: Integer);
var
  HeaderItem: THDItem;
begin
  HeaderItem.Mask := HDI_FORMAT or HDI_TEXT or HDI_LPARAM;
  Header_GetItem(FLVHeader, 1, HeaderItem);
  HeaderItem.Mask := HDI_FORMAT;
  HeaderItem.fmt := HeaderItem.fmt or HDF_OWNERDRAW;
  Header_SetItem(FLVHeader, 1, HeaderItem);
end;

procedure TForm1.LVWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  FSaveLVWndProc(Msg);    // thanks to @Kobik (cause SO if called later then WM_NOTIFY case on some (all other then mine?) machines)

  case Msg.Msg of
    WM_DRAWITEM:
      if (TWmDrawItem(Msg).DrawItemStruct.CtlType = ODT_HEADER) and
          (TWmDrawItem(Msg).DrawItemStruct.hwndItem = FLVHeader) and
          (TWmDrawItem(Msg).DrawItemStruct.itemID = 1) then
        SetTextColor(TWmDrawItem(Msg).DrawItemStruct.hDC, ColorToRGB(clRed));
    WM_NOTIFY:
      if (TWMNotify(Msg).NMHdr.hwndFrom = FLVHeader) and
          (TWMNotify(Msg).NMHdr.code = HDN_ITEMCHANGED) then
          // also try 'HDN_ENDTRACK' if it doesn't work as expected
        SetHeaderItemStyle(1);
    WM_DESTROY: ListView1.WindowProc := FSaveLVWndProc;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is a bug here. Try to resize the coloured column. The red colour goes away.

Comment: I think it may be due to TListColumn.SetWidth leading to TCustomListView.UpdateColumn which calls ListView_SetColumn with the column information as VCL knows it.

Comment: @Andreas, the [proper way](http://pastebin.com/1HFXkA4i) is to handle the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` and respond with `CDRF_NEWFONT` in the `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` stage... However, I can't figure out just the last thing, how to get the index of the header item.

Comment: @TLama - I think not, follow the link in the answer.

Comment: @Sertac, what would then the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775300(v=vs.85).aspx) header notification be for ?

Comment: @TLama: Your code works perfectly, if you only replace `AMessage.HDNotify.Item` by `NMCustomDraw.dwItemSpec` in your `FOnGetHeaderItemFontColor` call. Please post your code as an answer (with my correction, of course).

Comment: @Andreas - I applied a patch with `HDN_ITEMCHANGING` for the column resize bug

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: I get AV when I try to resize any of the columns.

Comment: @Andreas - Hmm, maybe something is different on your side.. I tried with a brand new project and it seems to work ok. Added 3 columns with captions to a listview and set the view style to vsReport is all I did in the OI.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Tried it a second time. Sill AV... It would be interesting to see what happens to a 'third party' testing this code. David, anyone?

Comment: @TLama, Sertac: I am not an expert on this topic, but I believe that Sertac's approach is '*owner* draw', while TLama's approach is '*custom* draw'. Also, I believe that the latter approach is more suitable.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the point about `NMCustomDraw.dwItemSpec`!

Comment: @TLama - That was what gave me a hard time, turns out it is actually even [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Good answer (+1) BTW..

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I also get an exception when trying to resize a column: `EStackOverflow` in `procedure TCustomListView.HeaderWndProc` line `Result := CallWindowProc(FDefHeaderProc, FHeaderHandle, Msg, WParam, LParam);` (D7/Win7)

Comment: @kobik - If you still have the test project would you mind testing 'Exit'ing in the 'WM_NOTIFY' handler: .. `then` `begin` `SetHeaderItemStyle(1);` `Exit;` `end;`

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, That was also my first thought (because of Stack Overflow). That didn't help.

Comment: @kobik - Thank you for the information. I better delete this answer. Andreas gets an EAccessViolation, you get an EStackOverflow, who knows what else.. And I can fix neither without being able to duplicate..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I also got an AV later if that makes a bit more happy :-P Which version of Delphi did you test? And which version Andreas test it?

Comment: @kobik - Yes, that's quite something for me... :) I tested with D7 (with/without manifest), D2007, XE2 (32bit) - OS W7x64. Andreas is using, AFAIR, D2009.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Strange... and D7 worked ok for you? I have seen some very strange behavior (AVs) of LV (in a non-unicode versions) combined with manifest (both D5/7). I ended up using `TTntListView` and the problems went away. I'm saying that because your comment line: `even for a non-unicode header window it's the *W* version (?)`

Comment: @kobik - That's a peculiarity of the OS, verified by also the VCL source: in `TCustomHeaderControl.CNNotify` there's a case branch: `HDN_ITEMCHANGEDA, HDN_ITEMCHANGEDW:`. VCL also couldn't risk using `HDN_ITEMCHANGED`.

Comment: @Kobik - Thank you very much for the fix! (I'll delete my comment on the other post after a while)